# VBA Shape.Top property not working correctly in Excel 365

Tags: vba

Last week i upgraded office from 16 to O365, everything seemed fine at the beginning...

I have a function that calls a userform to get a signature and place it on a hidden worksheet(layout) that will be printed in a second moment.
with office 16 i had no problems placing the signature on a hidden sheet, but with office O365, it just continues to assign the wrong top value...

I noticed that if the target sheet is active the top property of the target shape works fine, but if the sheet is not active o hidden, excel does not assign the correct value to the top property of the target shape. This issue was not present in office 2016.

Here is an example code:

```
Private Sub SetSignature()
    Dim userSign As Shape               'picture (shape)
    Dim filePth As String               'picture path
    Dim signatureRng As Range           'range at which the picture will be placed

    filePth = "C:\Users\UserX\Desktop\signature.png"

    Set signatureRng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("LayoutDoc").Range("A48")

    Set userSign = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("LayoutDoc").Shapes.AddPicture(filePth, False, True, 1, 1, 1, 1)
    With userSign
        .ScaleHeight 0.4, True
        .ScaleWidth 0.4, True
        .Top = signatureRng.Top - Application.CentimetersToPoints(0.3)
        .Left = signatureRng.Left + Application.CentimetersToPoints(0.1)
        .Name = "Signature1"
    End With

End Sub
```

And here is the full function:

```
Private Function GetSignature() As String
    Dim signaturePath As String                 'Signature path
    Dim userSign As Shape                       'Signature img
    Dim filePth As String                       'Signature file path
    Dim signatureRng As Range                   'range at which the signature should be placed
    Dim checkTopSignature As Boolean            'used to check if the picture top was set correctly
    Dim sheetVisibilty As Integer               'sheet visibility
    Dim curScreenUpSt As Boolean                'current screenupdating state
    
    filePth = PJ_PubVar.firmeTempDir & "\" & PJ_PubVar.kFirmaApPrepInt & nuovoPermesso.ID & PJ_PubVar.firmaExtenion
    
    'assign the range at which the signture will be placed
    Set signatureRng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(WB_PubVar.curWB_wsLayoutPermesso).Range(WB_PubVar.curWB_rngOraFirmaInizioInt)
    'get sheet visibility
    sheetVisibilty = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(WB_PubVar.curWB_wsLayoutPermesso).Visible
    'get current screenupdating state
    curScreenUpSt = Application.ScreenUpdating
    
    'userform to get the signature from the user
    With FormSignature
        .filePath = filePth
        .Show
    End With
    
    'if signature acquired, then save the signature address and add it to the document layout
    If firmaAquisita Then
        signaturePath = filePth
        'add the signature to the sheet (hidden)
        Set userSign = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("LayoutDoc").Shapes.AddPicture(signaturePath, False, True, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        'setup picture position and dimentions
        With userSign
            .ScaleHeight PJ_PubVar.perceMisuFirma, True
            .ScaleWidth PJ_PubVar.perceMisuFirma, True
            
        '******************************************************************************************************************************************
        '******************************************************************************************************************************************
        
        '**** 04/15/2022:
        '**** After switching to Office 365, I noticed that when the sheet is not active (or hidden) the top of the picture is assigned incorrectly
        '**** as a work arround I had to assign the same value of the top of the range to the image top
        '**** check if the values are the same, if they are the same (office 2016) I proceed normally
        '**** otherwise, I unlock the wb and activate the worksheet
        '**** I set top, left and name
        '**** set back the worksheet visiblity and the workbook protection as before
        
            'assign the same value of the top of the range to the image top
            .Top = signatureRng.Top
            
            'check if the values are the same
            checkTopSignature = (.Top = signatureRng.Top)
            
            If Not checkTopSignature Then
            'I unlock the wb and activate the worksheet
                Application.ScreenUpdating = False
                ThisWorkbook.Unprotect (WB_PubVar.curWB_Password)
                With Sheets(WB_PubVar.curWB_wsLayoutPermesso)
                    .Visible = xlSheetVisible
                    .Activate
                End With
                
                'set top, left and name of the picture
                .Top = signatureRng.Top - Application.CentimetersToPoints(PJ_PubVar.offsetFirmaInCm_H)
                .Left = signatureRng.Left + Application.CentimetersToPoints(PJ_PubVar.offsetFirmaInCm_W)
                .Name = WB_PubVar.curWB_imgFirmaInizioInt
                
                'set back the worksheet visiblity and the workbook protection as before
                Sheets(WB_PubVar.curWB_wsLayoutPermesso).Visible = sheetVisibilty
                ThisWorkbook.Protect (WB_PubVar.curWB_Password)
                Application.ScreenUpdating = curScreenUpSt
            Else
                .Top = signatureRng.Top - Application.CentimetersToPoints(PJ_PubVar.offsetFirmaInCm_H)
                .Left = signatureRng.Left + Application.CentimetersToPoints(PJ_PubVar.offsetFirmaInCm_W)
                .Name = WB_PubVar.curWB_imgFirmaInizioInt
            End If
        '******************************************************************************************************************************************
        '******************************************************************************************************************************************
        End With

    Else
        signaturePath = ""
    End If
    
    GetSignature = signaturePath
    
End Function
```

[Here is a screenshot of the issue.. even if i assign the range.top value to the picture.top, vba just ignores it...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIjOE.jpg)

Does anyone know what is wrong?
Is it a bug with office 365?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Working on O365 and quickly used your code: I don't have such issues, image is placed correctly no matter if sheet is hidden or not.

Comment: Yah i tried the example that i posted and it worked fine... but when i debug the function it gives different values..

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIjOE.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Hello i found you message and i have the same issue i thinks.

I just want position a picture in top left corner of a cell. The higher the index of the row, the more the offset is visible.

Exemple : https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJerH.jpg